# How to check/uncheck checkbox in clojurescript?

Tags: html, checkbox, clojure, clojurescript

This is what I've tried :

```
(set! (.-checked checkbox-element) true)
```

but it doesn't work. It should work ( based on http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp). Please, what is the correct way to check/uncheck checkbox  using clojurescript?

Comment: maybe :advanced compilation has changed the symbol. Try it with :none or :simple

Comment: @myguidingstar, could you maybe add that as an actual answer.

Comment: you're doing it right with the above code, so I guess the problem is in configuration stuff. Can you create a full repo somewhere so I can look at the whole things?

Comment: Actually the problem was somewhere else. I was using domina to select element. However the domina css function doesn't return javascript raw element and therefore this wasn't working. When using document.getElementById everything is ok.

Comment: I learnt that lesson the hard way as well. In general, if your using a clojure library to interact with the DOM, such as domina, I think its a good idea to be consistent and use the facilities the library provides whenever possible rather than mixing up use of the library and low level direct javascript interop. Not as big a risk with simple libs like domina, but can really cause difficult to track down problems if you start using libs like Reagent, which manage their own 'view' of the DOM state

Comment: Actually my initial problem was that I wasn't able to check/uncheck a checkbox with domina ( and I still can't).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using domina:

```
(set-attr! checkbox-element :checked "checked")
```

sets the checkbox, and

```
(remove-attr! checkbox-element :checked)
```

clears it.